# Windows 10 laptop suddently needs to boot csm mode

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi, asus-laptop

I recently bought a new asus laptop with windows 10 on it. I did a reinstall (of windows 10) and I have been using it after that for about a month or 2.

Suddenly it boots only to UEFI. When I was checking the boot options, none was there. Also my date time was reset. So I assumed that it was a HDD failure or a different kind of hardware failure. But when I tried to add a new boot option I could browse to the disks/partitions. So after some googling I switched off secure boot and enabled csm and it now boots back into windows!

The questions that I now have are:

1. Why do I have to enable csm in order to boot, while I didn't have to before?
2. Since my date time was reset, could it be that therefore secure boot was broken? And how to fix it?

Comment: Typically a time and date reset is a failed/dying CMOS battery, but on such a new laptop I find it hard to believe the CMOS is dying already.

Comment: Sounds like when you installed Windows 10 yourself you also enabled CSM

Comment: So that when I reinstalled windows 10, I eneabled csm already, but duo too the reset, it was set back to secure boot you mean?

I first found that plausible, but after rethinking: The boot is now different. First it showed the windows 10 loading spinner underneath the asus log. Now the asus logo disappears and the default windows 10 boot screen is shown with the loading spinner, just like on my desktop without secure/fast boot.

Comment: No need to speculate. Check the partition schema: Is it MBR or GPT?

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with asus I send the laptop to them and they did find a hardware failure. They replaced the ssd disk and everything seems to be running fine now.